# Developing for iOS4 with XCode 3.2

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

Can you develop for the latest iOS4, using XCode 3.2? Do I need to get the latst SDK? I know there is a new XCode coming out but it isnt released yet right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can: http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action